# Sprite frame animation javascript

Tags: javascript, sprite

Trying to edit the Alien Invaders on Github https://github.com/cykod/AlienInvasion with my own images. Have a spritesheet I created but don't know how to call a loop for the frames to work so that the enemys and ships will always be looping. They're drawn on the canvas with this.

```
var sprites = {
 ship: { sx: 0, sy: 1, w: 48, h: 70, frames: 10 },

 missile: { sx: 0, sy: 442, w: 15, h: 24, frames: 1 },

 enemy_purple: { sx: 0, sy: 125, w: 31, h: 62, frames: 1 },

 enemy_bee: { sx: 0, sy: 328, w: 34, h: 97, frames: 1 },

 enemy_ship: { sx: 0, sy: 198, w: 50, h: 116, frames: 1 },

 enemy_circle: { sx: 0, sy: 83, w: 34, h: 31, frames: 1 },

 explosion: { sx: 0, sy: 563, w: 73, h: 93, frames: 10 },

 enemy_missile: { sx: 0, sy: 493, w: 15, h: 24, frame: 1, }
};
```

How do I make ship move through its frames?